# how to run programs within a tightvnc session on windows

Tags: cygwin

I have a Win2K8 server and it hosts tightvnc server and cigwin for ssh connectivity. I want to run some UI programs using ssh connection like say IE. How to do it? if i run the applications i dont see them poping up if i connect to tightvnc session.

Steps :-

1. run tight vnc on serverX say on port 5900
2. open ssh connection to serverX and launch notepad.exe
3. using vncviewer connect to sererX:5900

I am expecting to see notepad BUT i dont see it. 
Please let me know what is the correct way to do this.

Thanks

Shankar KC

Answer (score 0):

If you login normally via ssh to cygwin you can't start a GUI application.

You can edit an [sshd_config file and pass that to sshd on startup](http://spectlog.com/content/Log:Stuff/Use_cygwin_sshd_to_start_application_remotely_in_user_GUI_session), making sure that the line starting UsePrivilegeSeparation is no as below

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation no
```

See also other answers below

Using PsExec: [How can I run a win32 gui program from cygwin ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110164/how-can-i-run-a-win32-gui-program-from-cygwin-ssh)

Using [Gnu Screen](https://superuser.com/questions/531787/starting-windows-gui-program-in-windows-through-cygwin-sshd-from-ssh-client)

Comment: i modified cygwin.bat file to run as application. NOT as service. Now i can run tests fine on ssh. I didnt use psexec though. when ssh runs as service windows vista onwards OS will block the UI as a security measure. As per the windows design services cannot have UI.